# Reflection of $x=1$ about $x+y=1$

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> A ray of light travels along the line $x=1$ and gets reflected by a mirror on $x+y=1$. Find the equation of the reflected ray.

$$$$

I am to solve this problem using only $\tan\theta=|\dfrac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}|$ where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the slopes of the lines between which the angle $\theta$ is subtended.$$$$

I know one way of solving it is to find  any general point on $x=1$, find its image about $x+y=1$ and  find the equation of the reflected ray using the 2 point form(once we have the point of intersection of $x=1$ and $x+y=1$. However, this method is not allowed by my teacher.

$$$$I would be grateful for any assistance. Many thanks.

Comment: you should define $\theta, m_1,  m_2$ above (especially since it means something geometrical). Then try to find what they could correspond to in your case. Then convert the geometric property of mirror to this. ;-)

Comment: Sorry. I'll do that now. Could you please show me how to find what they correspond to?

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET Assuming that $\theta$ is the angle subtended between the normal and the incident ray, I get the slope of the normal as 1, and the slope of the incident ray as $\infty$.

Comment: In geometry, you know things about the angle of the reflected ray as compare to the angle of the incident ray. Your formula is about $tan(\theta_1-\theta_2)$. It is used to work in slope space instead of angles space, i.e., to translate relations about angles into relations about slopes.

Comment: Sir, I know that the angle of incidence is equal to the angle of refraction. However I can't understand how to use it correctly in this question.

Comment: so you have $\theta_{in}-\theta_{mirror} = \theta_{mirror}-\theta_{out}$. and you can take $tan()$ on both sides. (but ok it sounds a bit silly to force that way of solving, especially with those numbers. Or their is a purpose here, line 2 exercices in 1.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the direction of the ray we get $(-\infty,1]$ or $[1,\infty)$:

[image]

Comment: Sir, I couldn't get your answer. I have to find the equation of the reflected ray.

Comment: The equation of the red horizontal line is $y=0$ if $x\le 1$ and it is not defined if $x>1$. The equation of the blue horizontal line is $y=0$ if $x\ge 1$ and not defined otherwise. The red and blue horizontal lines can be described as $y=0$. But the reflection depends on the direction of the ray coming along $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Graphs]

Not quite sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but perhaps you could approach it this way. Intuitively we know that the reflection would be the perpendicular of the line $x=1$. So we shall aim to show that algebraically.

For convenience, we shall rewrite $x+y=1$ as $y=-x+1$.

Let $\theta$ be the angle between $y=-x+1$ and $x=1$, and let $m_1, m_2$ be the slopes of the lines $y=-x+1$ and $x=1$ respectively. Now we define a slope $m_3$, which will become the slope of the reflected line. Since angle of incidence equals angle of reflection, we have the following equation necessarily.

\begin{align}
\tan \theta &= \left \lvert \frac{m_1 - m_2}{1+ m_1 m_2} \right \rvert = \left \lvert \frac{m_1 - m_3}{1+ m_1 m_3} \right \rvert
\end{align}

Now with $m_1 = -1$, we equate the following: 
\begin{align}
\left \lvert \frac{(-1)- m_2}{1- m_2} \right \rvert = \left \lvert \frac{(-1)- m_3}{1-m_3} \right \rvert
\end{align}

After some algebraic manipulation, we have $m_2 \cdot m_3 = -1$, verifying that the reflected line is the perpendicular of $x=1$. Since it passes through the point $(1,0)$, the equation of the reflected line must be $y=0$.